# ExceptionInInitializerError при запуске JavaFX приложения из другого класса

Tags: java, javafx

При создании экземпляра класса App в main класса Main в коде ниже возникает следующая ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at App.<clinit>(App.java:25)
at Main.main(Main.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Код (Main):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    App app = new App();
}
```

Код (App):

```
public class App extends Application {
private static Button btn_start = new Button("start");
private static TextField field_currentLink = new TextField("current link");
private static TextArea field_result = new TextArea();
public void start(Stage stage) {
    FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    root.getChildren().add(field_result);
    root.getChildren().add(field_currentLink);
    root.getChildren().add(btn_start);
    stage.setTitle("some application");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

До этого читал [аналогичный вопрос на иноязычном StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025718/javafx-toolkit-not-initialized-when-trying-to-play-an-mp3-file-through-mediap/43277386), но приведенные там методы решения не помогли.

Comment: На какой из приведенных строк возникает исключение (`App.java:25`)? И приведите ссылку на то какие методы решения не помогли.

Comment: Строка "private static Button...", методы добавил в сам вопрос

Comment: Что-то тот вопрос не очень аналогичен. В нем нет ничего про эту ошибку.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ExceptionInInitializerError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html) это ошибка, которая возникает когда во время статической инициализации класса выбрасывается исключение.

Из документации:

> Signals that an unexpected exception has occurred in a static initializer. ...
>   Сообщает о том, что неожиданная ошибка возникла в статическом инициализаторе. ...

Например, если в классе есть такое поле:

```
private static int nullLength = ((String) null).length();
```

, то при первом обращении к классу виртуальная машина попытается его инициализировать. При этом возникнет `NullPointerException`, но это исключение будет обернуто в `ExceptionInInitializerError` т.к. неинициализированный класс достаточно серьезная проблема, которую разработчику сложно будет обработать и исправить (предназначение [`Error`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)).

**Пути исправления.**

Для исправления ошибки нужно найти оригинальное исключение. Возможные варианты:

- Избавиться от статической инициализации. Если поля не используются в нескольких разных объектах, то их не нужно делать статическими. Попробуйте убрать `static` из объявления поля и использующих его методов и посмотрите что получится.

  ```
  private Button btn_start = new Button("start");
  private TextField field_currentLink ...
  ```

  Ошибки, возникшие при инициализации полей класса уже не будут оборачиваться в `Error` и Вы сможете увидеть оригинальное исключение.
  В Вашем случае это, скорее всего, `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized` по причине того, что элементы создаются до инициализации платформы. Посмотрите аналогичный вопрос на английском: [JavaFX issue with static keyword; with Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36793534/javafx-issue-with-static-keyword-with-minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)
- Просмотреть до конца трассировку стека по ошибке. Метод [`getCause()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html#getCause()) возвращает оригинальное исключение и обычно это исключение включается в вывод по ошибке. Для примера выше выводится:

  ```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:10)
  ```
- Поймать ошибку. Можно повесить обработчик ошибок на уровне потока и обработать его вручную.

  ```
  Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
      public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
          if (e instanceof ExceptionInInitializerError) {
              Exception originalException = e.getCause();
              //выводим куда-нибудь исключение
          }
      }
  });
  ```
- Обрабатывать ошибки при инициализации. Перенести инициализацию переменных в методы, либо блоки и обрабатывать ошибки самому.

  ```
  private static int nullLength;

  static {
      try {
           nullLength = ((String) null).length();
      } catch(Exception e) {
           //выводим исключение куда-нибудь.
      }
  }
  ```

После того как найдете оригинальное исключение его нужно будет как-то обрабатывать и/или устранять. Но это уже совсем другая история.

Answer (score 0):

Я сейчас использую *android studio* на *java*, *Retrofit*, *GSON* и *RxJava*.

Мне помогла актуализация  в `build.gradle.kts`:

```
compileSdk = 34
targetSdk = 34

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

// RxJava

    implementation ("io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.21")

// RxAndroid

    implementation ("io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1")

// Для использования RxJava с Retrofit

    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.7.1")
    implementation ("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0")

// Retrofit & OkHttp

    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation ("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0")

// JSON Converter (Gson converter)

    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"  
tools:targetApi="31"
```